# Extending SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration with custom HttpSecurity configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to gain a better understanding of the auto-configuration of spring boot. In particular I need to add some custom spring security configuration to disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS verbs in order to get my CORS requests working.

Without any custom configuration by default the `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` is loaded by Spring Boot's auto-configuration.

What I would like to do is to keep using this auto-configuration but add some additional http configuration. I tried this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger (SecurityConfiguration.class);
    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info ("--- ALLOW all HTTP OPTIONS Requests");
        http.authorizeRequests ().antMatchers (HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "*//**").permitAll ();
    }
}
```

But this does not work as excepted. When I debug through `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` and also the above code, I can see that both my `configure`-method and springs auto-configuration are executed but it looks like my `http`-configuration takes precedence.

So does that mean the auto-configuration is available only in an *all-or-nothing* kind of way? Or can I use the the auto-configuration but still extend it with some custom antMatcher?

What is the best-practice for this scenario?

Comment: Shouldn't your SecurityConfiguration class be annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new servlet filter and place it before the Spring security filter. For example:

```
@Component("CORSFilter")
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest req, 
        ServletResponse res, 
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException,  ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "THE_HOST_YOU_WANT_TO_ALLOW_HERE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with, authorization");

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("OK");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                 //... 
            }
         } else {
             chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        //...
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //...
    }

}
```

and then add this to your web.xml (or configure in your WebInitializer if you are using Java config only):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.[YOUR_SERVLET_NAME]</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I was looking specifically for a solution that lets me extend the Spring Boot configuration. You are instead suggesting to configure a filter mapping which Spring Boot is already taking care of for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot do it is you are missing the annotation `@EnableWebSecurity`, have a look at the javadoc:

```
 * Add this annotation to an {@code @Configuration} class to have the Spring Security
 * configuration defined in any {@link WebSecurityConfigurer} or more likely by extending
 * the {@link WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter} base class and overriding individual methods:
```

Comment: No thats not the reason, this will cause Spring Boot to not use its own configuration. I want to extend the configuration, not replace it completely.